# Can somebody give me a tutorial link to install magento on Centos8?

Tags: installation, repository, centos

Can i get a link to some kind of tutorial that works for installing magento 2 on centos 8 i try to follow what is currently on google but they dont work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://bash-prompt.net/guides/magento-centos-8-10m/

check this tutorial the only one that works at least for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a difference in the way you install Magneto2 in any of Linux distribution.

The easiest way is also the right one - trough composer. Just make sure you have composer configured. 
 You'll find it at the official link: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/composer.html

But just a short resume:

```
 # install the project 
 $ composer create-project --repository=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition <project-name>


 # set file permissions 
 cd <project-name>
 find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} +
 find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +
 chown -R :www-data .
 chmod u+x bin/magento
```

make sure to rename  - into something appropriate to your needs.

And then just go on website link and follow the wizard setup.

Comment: ok and the php versions ? and all that module this thing need ?

Comment: Are you asking about requirements? You'll find them at: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Answer (score 0):

we have Magento 2 LEMP webstack configuration script available now for CentOS 8.

https://magenx.sh/

to install full ecommerce webstack, you need to run:

```
curl -o magenx.sh https://magenx.sh && bash magenx.sh
```

this script will install everything you need to start Magento 2 development, and good for production too. While CentOS 8 has some minor bugs and issues, if you have skills it will be easy for you to run it as you like.

ps. simple bash script, text file, human friendly, just a collection of all commands you run to install webstack.

Comment: thanks for this script but I already installed it the hard way... so nginx is better for magento ? what about nginx and apache ?

Comment: this is about what you like, you only need one server. either nginx or apache.